# Updating Label text tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def text_to_binary(convert):
    for x in convert: # iterates over each character in the list
        ascii_values = ord(x) #gets the ascii value for x
        binary = format(ascii_values,'b')
        if len(binary) == 7:
            tk.Label(text="'0',binary")
            tk.Label.pack()
        elif len(binary) == 6:
            tk.Label(text="'00',binary")
            tk.Label.pack()
        else:
            tk.Label(text=binary)
            tk.Label.pack()

###MAINLINE###
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Binary Converter')
window.geometry("450x120")

entry = tk.Entry(width=50)
entry.pack()

result = entry.get()

btn_convert = tk.Button(text='Convert it!', command=text_to_binary(result))
btn_convert.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I want to use the function I created to convert bianry, it does that, but I don't know how to get that running with tkinter gui. Little help?

Comment: Could you explain what this code is doing right now so we can help better? Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the issues in your code:

- both `from tkinter import *` and `import tkinter as tk` are executed.  Wildcard import is not recommended, so remove `from tkinter import *`;
- calling `result = entry.get()` right after `entry` is created, so `result` will be empty string;
- `command=text_to_binary(result)` will execute `text_to_binary(result)` immediately without clicking the button. It should be `command=lambda: text_to_binary(entry.get())` instead;
- `tk.Label.pack()` will raise exception. `.pack()` should be called on instance of `tk.Label()`;

Below is the modified code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def text_to_binary(convert):
    # clear existing result
    for w in result.winfo_children():
        w.destroy()

    for x in convert: # iterates over each character in the list
        ascii_values = ord(x) #gets the ascii value for x
        binary = format(ascii_values, '08b')
        tk.Label(result, text=binary).pack()

###MAINLINE###
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Binary Converter')
#window.geometry("450x120")

entry = tk.Entry(window, width=50)
entry.pack()

btn_convert = tk.Button(window, text='Convert it!', command=lambda: text_to_binary(entry.get()))
btn_convert.pack()

# frame for the conversion result
result = tk.Frame(window)
result.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to convert from string to binary.

Put the `Entry` widget outside of the function and use `configure` inside the function. It is critically widely practical.

The command when using Method join() + ord() + format().

```
import tkinter as tk


def text_to_binary()->None:
    test_str = entry.get()
    result = ''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in test_str)))
    lbl_binary.configure(text=result)
            
         
###MAINLINE###
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Binary Converter')
window.geometry("450x120")

entry = tk.Entry(width=50)
entry.pack()

result = entry.get()

lbl_binary = tk.Label(window)
lbl_binary.pack()

btn_convert = tk.Button(text='Convert it!', command=text_to_binary)
btn_convert.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

The command when using Method join() + bytearray() + format()

```
import tkinter as tk 

def text_to_binary()->None:
    test_str = entry.get()
    result = ''.join(format(i, '08b') for i in bytearray(test_str, encoding ='utf-8'))
    lbl_binary.configure(text=result)
            
         
###MAINLINE###
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Binary Converter')
window.geometry("450x120")

entry = tk.Entry(width=50)
entry.pack()

result = entry.get()

lbl_binary = tk.Label(window)
lbl_binary.pack()

btn_convert = tk.Button(text='Convert it!', command=text_to_binary)
btn_convert.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Using an empty list to store binary values.

```
import tkinter as tk

def text_to_binary()-> None:
    test_str = entry.get()
    result = [bin(ord(char))[2:].zfill(8)for char in test_str]
    lbl_binary.configure(text=result)
     
                     
###MAINLINE###
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Binary Converter')
window.geometry("500x120")

entry = tk.Entry(width=50)
entry.pack()

lbl_binary = tk.Label(window)
lbl_binary.pack()

btn_convert = tk.Button(text='Convert it!', command=text_to_binary)
btn_convert.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]